# Removing Space Separator From Tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I was wondering if there was a way to remove the space separator from a tuple in Python 3.6. For example, if I were to have:

```
t1 = (x,y)
print(t1)
```

The output would be

```
(x, y)
```

but I want it to be

```
(x,y)
```

without the space that separates the indices. Is there a way to do this?

EDIT: Thanks for the helpful answers so far, I believe I was not specific enough however. I want to consider the following class:

```
class Example(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return '({0},{1})'.format(self.x, self.y)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y
```

Which is then called and executed in the same file (I know classes should be in separate files but bear with me here) with the following code:

```
if __name__ == 'main':
    ex1 = Example(0,12)
    ex2 = Example(5,10)

    print('ex1 - ex2 =', str(ex1-ex2))
```

How can I accomplish the initial problem (removing the space from the tuple), without altering any of the code below `if __name__ == 'main'`?

Comment: Generally speaking, the answer to "how do I control the way this built-in type displays itself?" is "construct a string that has the properties you want, and print that instead".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around more with my own code, I seem to have solved my own problem. Thanks to everyone who helped! The solution was as easy as calling the class again on the return statement in the `__sub__` method because I guess that Python was passing it to the built-in `str` method instead of my own. The updated code is as follows:

```
class Example(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return '({0},{1})'.format(self.x, self.y)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Example(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y)
```

Posted my own solution just in case someone else has this problem in the future.

Answer (score 1):

That's the default output for Python's `print` statement.

You can custom-format a string to show what you want:

```
print('({0},{1})'.format(t1[0],t1[1]))
```

Comment: Remember that he is using python 3.x

Comment: Right.  I didn't notice that in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following examples:

```
print('%s%s' % ('one', 'two'))
print('{}{}'.format('one', 'two'))
```

For more references: https://pyformat.info/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the tuple having two entries is probably not the best idea. Something like:

```
print('({})'.format(','.join(map(str, tup))))
```

would be safer.